# Search for route of travel schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

#### Situation

We are implementing a search where you can search schedules by from where to where you want to go.

#### Definitions

1. If from and to mach schedules from and to it's easy and all stops are returned
2. If from and to match  exactly one leg, only that leg is returned
3. If from and to are on different legs, these two legs and maybe legs between are returned

#### DB schema

Schedule

- ID (primary key)
- Name

Leg

- ID (primary key)
- Origin_ID (foreign key)
- Destination_ID (foreign key)
- Schedule_ID (foreign key to schedule table)
- ETD (iso 8601 date string)
- ETA (iso 8601 date string)

#### Example

Schedule:

```
|---------|--------------|--------------|
|    ID   |    Origin    | Destination  |
|---------|--------------|--------------|
|    1    |  Airport A   |  Airport B   |
|---------|--------------|--------------|
|    2    |  Airport B   |  Airport C   |
|---------|--------------|--------------|
|    3    |  Airport C   |  Airport D   |
|---------|--------------|--------------|
|    4    |  Airport D   |  Airport E   |
|---------|--------------|--------------|
|    5    |  Airport E   |  Airport F   |
|---------|--------------|--------------|
```

- Person 1 wants to go from **Airport X** to **Airport Y**

  - no results
- Person 2 wants to go from **Airport A** to **Airport F**

  - return whole schedule
- Person 3 wants to go from **Airport B** to **Airport C**

  - return schedule with only leg 2
- Person 4 wants to go from **Airport C** to **Airport F**

  - return schedule with leg 3, 4 and 5
- Person 5 wants to go from **Airport D** to **Airport B**

  - no results

#### Pseudocode

1. Find Schedules

   ```
   SELECT
       ScheduleID AS ID
   FROM
       Leg
   WHERE
       ScheduleID IN (
           SELECT
               ScheduleID
           FROM
              Leg
           WHERE
               Leg.Origin_ID = from AND
               ETD > DateAdd(day, -1, getUTCDate())
       ) AND
       Leg.Destination_ID = to
   GROUP BY
       ScheduleID, ETD
   ORDER BY
       ETD
   ```
2. Get schedule's legs

   ```
   SELECT
       convert(char(20), Leg.ETD AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 127) AS ETD,
       convert(char(20), Leg.ETA AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 127) AS ETA,
       Leg.Origin_ID, Leg.Destination_ID, Leg.ScheduleID, Leg.ID
   FROM
       Leg
   INNER JOIN
       Schedule ON Schedule.ID = Leg.ScheduleID
   WHERE
       Leg.ScheduleID IN (<!-- IDs from query above -->)
   ORDER BY
       Leg.ScheduleID, Leg.ETD
   ```
3. Filter applicable legs

   ```
   var res = [];
   loop over 2nd query group="Schedule_ID"
       var start = false;
       var end = false;
       var currentSchedule = {
           'id': Schedule_ID,
           'legs': []
       };
       inner loop
           if (Origin_ID is from) {
               currentSchedule.legs.push(ID);
               currentSchedule['etd'] = ETD;
               start = true;
           }

           if (start) {
               if (not currentSchedule.legs.includes(ID)) {
                   currentSchedule.legs.push(ID);
               }
               if (Destination_ID is to) {
                  currentSchedule['eta'] = ETA;
               }
           }
   res.push(currentSchedule);
   ```

#### Problem

This code works but I'm a bit dissatisfied with the resulting code. I wonder if there's a way to refactor the code so that there are less steps and maybe less looping to make it faster and better to debug.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Why is there a `Schedule_ID` in `Leg`? What does your data look like? Can you provide a schema sample?

Comment: Every leg belongs to schedule. The schedule is a container. So `Schedule_ID` is the foreign key from `Leg` table to `Schedule` table's primary key.

Comment: Sorry, I was more asking about the db design. I don't know what your schema looks like, but it seems that a `Leg` should be independent of a `Schedule`, but a `Schedule_ID` should be made up of `Leg`s.  Anyway, would it be possible for you to put up an example schema?

Comment: "Should be independent" is what you understood from my example or what you think would be the proper approach? If the former applies then no, a leg has always a schedule.

Comment: UPDATE: I added a "db schema" section to the question

Answer (score 0):

First query returns the legs that match exactly on both `from` and `to` You don't need to use an inner `IN (SELECT...)` on the same table. Just filter on `Leg` directly :

```
SELECT
    ScheduleID AS ID
FROM
    Leg
WHERE
    Origin_ID = from
    AND ETD > DateAdd(day, -1, getUTCDate())
    AND Destination_ID = to
GROUP BY
    ScheduleID, ETD
ORDER BY
    ETD
```

Second query looks ok.

Third part of the code does not really make sense to me.

Comment: Your query looks for legs which have both from and to, but from and to just have to be in the schedule. They might be in the same leg but might be on different legs otherwise as long as to is after from.

After the second query I have all the legs of the schedule but I just need the legs which are applicable to the passengers route.